# og:title and og:description for share dialogs in different languages on the same page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

recently i worked on a project to add English version of contents to a Japanese website.
i wanted to remain the numbers of Facebook share on each page so i used a php parameter to switch English and Japanese.

```
<?php 
if ($ln == "en") {
CONTENTS IN ENGLISH;
} else {
CONTENTS IN JAPANESE;
}
?>
```

at the very top of each page, GET the language parameter then determine which contents should be shown.
and also i wrote 2 sets of ogp meta tags in each language and tried to switch them as i did for contents, but when i clicked the share buttons, their share dialogs were always in Japanese.

i guess it's because their canonical urls - without any parameters - were in the default language, Japanese.
i don't want to change their og:urls since it is said that og:url should be without parameters on this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#basic

and i don't want to reset num of share.

i set og:locale tags like this:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="ja_JP">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US">
```

i saw an article says Facebook fetches a website with "fb_locale" parameter if i set an og:locale:alternate tag.
is this true? i prepared ogp tags in case of "fb_locale" is en_US like this:

```
<?php 
if ($ln == "en" || $fb_locale == "en_US") {
ogp tags IN ENGLISH;
} else {
ogp tags IN JAPANESE;
}
?>
```

but it didn't work. i'm not sure which cached information Facebook looks for when i click the share button, and texts in share dialogs are still in Japanese.

also i found this article:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/

but i wouldn't like to let them get translated by API, just want to set specific og:titles and og:descriptions up to selected laguage.
i couldn't find exactly the same issues, so i really appreciate if you explain how to enable that or share any documents about the process.

thank you.

Comment: `og:locale` only works for objects used in Open Graph Stories, but not for normal posts that include them as the link. // You rather _should_ have two different URLs for those two language versions - not only concerning Facebook, but search engines as well. Yes, you are going to loose already accumulated likes - but IMHO doing it any other way is just going to lead to more trouble and problems in the end.

Comment: As a compromise, you could perhaps keep the existing URLs for the original Japanese content, and have the new English content reside under “new” URLs. That would at least allow you to keep the existing likes for the JP content.